# Querying in advance with linq2sql for data with different signs

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have a table with id, value and timestamp.  Timestamp is when the value was inserted into the table.  Value can be positive or negative.

How can I implement a smart LINQ query that will order this data by timestamp and take only those which one after another has different sign.

For example if I have values:

```
1 2011-03-20 5
2 2011-03-21 6
3 2011-03-22 -3
4 2011-03-23 -4
5 2011-03-24 2
```

I want to get only those with id:2,3 because they are different signs and 4,5

I could get them all and foreach them locally but I have more than 1 million such a values.

Comment: This one is even difficult in pure Sql, I think. You'd have to SELF JOIN with the table and then use ROW_NUMBER() in some way, because you can't assume continuous IDs. I'd probably use a SqlDataReader and run through all of them real quick. Implementing this logic is much easier in a loop and with some state.

Comment: One alternative is a stored procedure, which you can then use with L2S again. Better, if the SQL server is not on the same machine.

Comment: Do you always have continuous dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having continuous set of dates makes it much easier. Here is a query:

```
 IQueryable<YourType> dates = ...;

 var result = dates
                .Join(dates, d => d.TimeStamp.AddDays(1), 
                             d => d.TimeStamp, 
                             (d1, d2) => new {d1, d2})
                .Where(p => p.d1.Value * p.d2.Value < 0);
```

I've tested it locally and it works. Here is a query which is sent to SQL server:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[TimeStamp], [t0].[Value], [t1].[id] AS [id2], [t1].[TimeStamp] AS [TimeStamp2], [t1].[Value] AS [Value2]
FROM [dbo].[Dates] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Dates] AS [t1] ON DATEADD(ms, (CONVERT(BigInt,@p0 * 86400000)) % 86400000, DATEADD(day, (CONVERT(BigInt,@p0 * 86400000)) / 86400000, [t0].[TimeStamp])) = [t1].[TimeStamp]
WHERE ([t0].[Value] * [t1].[Value]) < @p1',N'@p0 float,@p1 int',@p0=1,@p1=0
```

Comment: ok but isnt't that in this case i need to have them all localy? what i am looking for is L2S query which will be translate to sql and query only those data what i am looking fore, if this is possible with current technology, what i not sure.

Comment: It is linq-2-sql, query is being handled by SQL.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Be aware though, that this query will only work correctly, if every date only occurs once in the table (as per the comment on your original question).

Comment: It will also only work, if really every day is entered into the table. As soon, as a day is missing, it can produce incorrect results.

Comment: Yes, it has very many limitations, but these limitations allow writing pretty simple query.

Comment: @Snowbear JIM-compiler: Yes, it is really nice. Was just adding that for the OP :)

Comment: well it is really nice. how did you test what will be sql query? sql profiler or you have some other tools?